# online bus booking

Tags: php, analytics, code-analysis

online bus booking

project is online bus booking, i expecting some suggestion from gurus,

Assume this is the sitution, but capcity is 30, so far 25 seat are booked,

How to handle the situation, when two user trying for booking the 4 tickets,

Assume, When user x viewing the site, system say still 5 seats are avaiable,

This same status user y also viewing, now both user started their booking,

Assume x and y user required 4 seats, what will happen, how to handle this complex situtaion,

Becuase we should fool the customer, that is, after payment gateway we should not say, Sorry for inconvience , their is not seats avaiable,

So i need one best logic, with that i have tom maintain this booking process,

truly i dont have any idea how to handle this situtaion.

Comment: 1) use transactions.  2) have more states than "free" and "booked".  Also include a "reserved" state when users start the checkout. If checkout doesn't complete in a reasonable time, return the reserved seats to free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Scaling temporary records in database to count totals to stop over-subscribing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8069503/367456)

Comment: @lion: online bus booking, stuck with logic when more than user trying for allocating less number of tickets

Answer (score 4):

You should do what most ticket selling services do in this situation. As soon as a user clicks to buy the tickets (Before entering any payment info) then mark the tickets as "reserved" on your backend like @GordonM said and time stamp them. If the transaction is not completed within a given time then the tickets are marked as "open" again and can be purchased. Just remember to let the customer know that they have to complete the transaction before their chance at the tickets "expires". Also it wouldn't hurt to add some AJAX to your ordering page that updates the available tickets every so often and more often the closer you get the the departure of the bus so that you can provided your customers with the most up-to-date numbers